# Google Realtime file becomes unreadable/inaccessible, always returning Error 500

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api

A couple of Realtime files I was working on yesterday are now apparently inaccessible, and though I can load metadata...

```
gapi.client.drive.files.get({ 'fileId': session.fileId });
```

...I can't load them:

```
gapi.drive.realtime.load(session.fileId, onRTFileLoaded, initializeRTModel, handleErrors);
```

I get a SERVER_ERROR (500) every time. Other files I've created today load fine.

My questions are, are there any known circumstances/actions which can lead to this? And what is the standard/prescribed way to deal with Error 500? And while we're at it... what IS an error 500? I've read that it can happen intermittently, but this is consistent (today). Safe to assume the files are gone for good - which, at the moment, doesn't matter - ?

**Additional info:**

- It's completely conceivable that I managed in some way to mix-and-match files, as I've been playing with closing a file and opening another on the same page. A Frankenfile is by no means out of the question.
- I haven't changed the (custom) structure of the files, nor the custom type registration code in any way since their creation.
- I could have done almost anything (though only via the regular Realtime API) to the files themselves.

This is the console info I get:

```
Drive Realtime API Error: server_error: Server returned unexpected HTTP status: 500              api:290
(anonymous function) api:290
Ti                   api:121
cs                   api:91
c.fb                 api:182
ud                   api:36
c.zb                 api:164
k.onreadystatechange api:133
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a production bug today that caused some documents to return 500s.  The bug has been fixed and the fix is in the final stages of being rolled out.  Sorry!  Please let me know if you continue to see this issue much beyond this post.

Comment: Don't know why, but I laughed aloud at that. And yes, lo-and-behold they're working again. Of course, I might not have the same reaction in a month or two when my fame, fortune, and general all-round adorability are resting on this working consistently for me and my millions of customers... but for now, I hugely appreciate the work you folks are doing on realtime.

Comment: I guess the other questions about Error 500 still stand, though: is best practice to just keep trying with exponential backoff, giving up after some period?

Comment: Yes, retrying with exponential backoff is always a good idea.  We know that lots of people depend on this working *all* the time, and try hard to make it so!  As always, we will institute additional release testing to ensure that this issue doesn't pop again.  (Note that you can check this page for outages: http://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en&v=status)

Comment: Ps, curious what you are building, if its public yet!

Comment: Not public quite yet (I'm still trying to work out the name, does "bing docs" or "yahoo docs" sound better to you?) I'm really impressed with realtime; last time I was actually _inspired_ by a technology was probably the introduction of .NET - don't quite know why, judging by SO at least, there seem to be (relatively) few of us working on it.